# How to display variable from .ts file to .html file in angular 17

Tags: html, typescript, angular17

I have this scenario. I have a table of products and for each product i have a button to open a dialog where i want to display some details about each product, including a input field.
This is my code. Im am using angular material. Any valid answer is greatly appreciated

> products.component

```
sellProduct(product:Product){
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(SellProductComponent,{
      width: '330px',
      height: '400px',
      data:{product:product}
    })
  }
```

> SellproductComponent.ts down below

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-sell-product',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MatFormFieldModule,FormsModule,MatDialogModule,MatInputModule],
  templateUrl: './sell-product.component.html',
  styleUrl: './sell-product.component.scss'
})
export class SellProductComponent {

  buyQuantity = 1;
  product:Product;

  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data:Product){}
  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.data)
    this.product.name=this.data.name
    this.product.quantity=this.data.quantity
  }
  sellProduct() {
    //to be implemented
  }
}
```

> and the html

````
<h2 mat-dialog-title>{{data.name}}</h2>
<mat-dialog-content>
 <div class="product-details">
    <h3>Price: {{data.price}}</h3>
    <h3>Quantity: {{data.quantity}}</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="buy-quantity">
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Buy Quantity</mat-label>
      <input matInput [(ngModel)]="buyQuantity" type="number" name="buyQuantity">
    </mat-form-field>
 </div>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions>
 <button mat-button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
 <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="sellProduct()">Buy</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>```

for some reasons data.name is not displaying anything.



I tried with [[]] but no success
````